# Uicollectionview -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory] crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

i am experiencing above issue when deque of a collection view cell. i have also register collection view nib in view did load.

```
if(IS_IPAD)
    {
        [prizesCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PrizesCollectionViewCell_iPad" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PrizesCell_iPad"];
        [leagueCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"LeagueCollectionViewCell_iPad" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"LeagueCell_iPad"];
    }
    else{
        [prizesCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PrizesCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PrizesCell"];
        [leagueCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"LeagueCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"LeagueCell"];
    }
```

and in a collection view i have this code :

```
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if(collectionView.tag == 0)
        {
            NSString *nibName ;
            static NSString *cellId;
            if(IS_IPAD)
            {
                nibName = @"PrizesCollectionViewCell_iPad";
                cellId = @"PrizesCell_iPad";
            }
            else
            {
                nibName = @"PrizesCollectionViewCell";
                cellId = @"PrizesCell";
            }
            PrizesCollectionViewCell *prizesCollectionCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
            if(prizesCollectionCell == nil)
            {
                prizesCollectionCell = (PrizesCollectionViewCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"PrizesCollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            if (prizesResult .count != 0)
            {
                NSString *tempStr = [[prizesResult objectAtIndex:(indexPath.item)%prizesResult.count] valueForKey:@"Image"];
                NSString *reqImageName = [tempStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".." withString:@""];
                NSString *imgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",imagesBaseUrl,reqImageName];
                [prizesCollectionCell.prizesImgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]];
                prizesCollectionCell.datesLbl.text=[[prizesResult objectAtIndex:(indexPath.item)%prizesResult.count] valueForKey:@"PrizeDescription"];
                prizesCollectionCell.prizeNoLbl.text = [[prizesResult objectAtIndex:(indexPath.item)%prizesResult.count] valueForKey:@"PrizeTitle"];
                return prizesCollectionCell;

            }
        }
 return nil;

}
```

and when i run the code i am getting this error :

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/UICollectionView.m:3454


*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier PrizesCell_iPad - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to register class:  `[prizesCollectionView registerClass:[PrizesCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PrizesCell_iPad"];`

Comment: Here i found this as you can register a class or a nib file . also i have tried registering class instead of nib but result was same.


Important: You must register a class or nib file using the
registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: or
registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.

Comment: Maybe the condition `if(collectionView.tag == 0)` isn't correct? It is a `leagueCollectionView`?

Comment: collectionview.tag == 0 for prizes cell and collectionview.tag == 1 is for league cell